# How to add current user field to view field list, when it has no relation to the content?

Tags: 7, views, users

**Is it possible to add the current user-id in the rewrite results of a View Field ?**

I have created a view of fields of a custom content type "Document". My goal is to rewrite the `Document: Title`-field to a hyperlink of the following format:

http://mysite.com/download.php?u=[user-id]&docid=[document-fid]

where `user-id` is the id of the currently logged-in user, and `[document-fid]` is the id of the file in the records of the view.

I know full well that before you can use a certain field in a rewrite, it needs to be added to the fields list of the view, and it has to be placed *before* the field you want  rewritten. But here is the problem. When I click "add" in the fields list, I don't see a `User`, or a `User: Current`-field.

Please bare in mind that `User: Current` has absolutely NO relation to the `author` of the item, or any other user related to the document. Therefor I cannot use the Relationships, under the Advanced section in views.

Please advise.

Comment: Please, specify Drupal version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is an answer for Drupal 7.**

You can

- use Views template system and rewrite output of the field (will work only for Views) or
- create own formatter for file field (will work everywhere for fields with this formatter) or
- alter any file path in [`hook_file_url_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_url_alter/7) (will work everywhere without settings)

I will show how to create field formatter. It will correctly work with standard node rendering, Views, Panels, etc.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function YOURMODULE_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    // Our own formatter for 'file' field
    'YOURMODULE_file_link' => array(
      'label' => t('Special download link'),
      'field types' => array('file'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function YOURMODULE_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  global $user;
  // Now just hide field if user not logged in
  if (user_is_anonymous()) {
    return;
  }

  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'YOURMODULE_file_link':
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        // Some title
        $title = isset($item['description']) ? $item['description'] : $item['filename'];
        // Theme link (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_link/7)
        $element[$delta] = array(
          '#theme' => 'link',
          '#text' => $title,
          '#path' => 'download.php',
          '#options' => array(
                        'attributes' => array(),
                        'html' => FALSE,
                        'query' => array('u' => $user->uid, 'document-fid' => $item['fid'])
                      )
        );

      }
      break;

  }
  return $element;
}
```

Add this code to your module (replace `YOURMODULE` with your module name), enable module, clear the cache if needed. New formatter will be available in Views field settings and in standard content type display settings.
[image: Select new formatter for field]

Comment: Worked like a charm!